# Page doesn't redirect using PageReference class

Tags: apex

Why page didn't redirect?

I wrote this statement:

```
PageReference pr = Site.login(username, password, '/apex/Homepage');
```

Comment: Can you post your method? I think you need to return the Pagereference as well from your method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set use the `setRedirect` method of the `PageReference` class then return this `PageReference` instance in your function:

```
PageReference pr = Site.login(username, password, '/apex/Homepage');
pr.setRedirect(true);
return pr;
```

Comment: I added the setRedirect method. But it shows error like this:"Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!login}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page loginpage: Class.SiteLoginController1.login: line 46, column 1

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified."